# Couldn't perform click, button not found in: Error in Test Rigor

Tags: testrigor

Website link https://www.bio123.de/
Below is my piece of code
switch to tab "1"

click  "Alles akzeptieren"

The button is not identified inside the pop up and error is thrown . Not only this none of the button inside the pop up is working and failing I have also tried to do enter escape that didnt work too

Answer (score 0):

Try using the OCR suffix after the button name:

click "Alles akzeptieren" using OCR

Comment: Thanks . I tried using this way . Same error occurs .  Meanwhile can you refer me why and when should i use OCR